# How to convert key value pairs of rcParams to dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to get `key:value` pairs of `rcParams` for further manipulation.

```
from matplotlib import rcParams 
x = rcParams
print(x)
```

Yeilds:

```
_internal.classic_mode: False
agg.path.chunksize: 0
animation.bitrate: -1
animation.codec: h264
animation.convert_args: ['-layers', 'OptimizePlus']
animation.convert_path: convert
...
```

I tried this approach:

```
for line in x:
    print(line)
```

It only yielded the `keys` but not the `values`:

```
_internal.classic_mode
agg.path.chunksize
animation.bitrate
animation.codec
animation.convert_args
animation.convert_path
...
```

Lastly I tried this:

```
for line in x:
    for key, value in line:
        print(key, value)
```

And received the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

What should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rcParams is a subclass of dict, so you should already be able to perform dict methods on the object. That being said, if you need to take an dict-like object like this and turn it into a separate dictionary, you can do something like this:

```py
from matplotlib import rcParams 

params = rcParams
new_params = {}

# with a simple for loop
for param in params:
    new_params[param] = params[param]
    
# or with the items() method
for param, value in params.items():
    new_params[param] = value
```

Answer (score 3):

`rcParams` object type is just a subclass of `dict`, which means you can still use dictionary methods like `.keys`/`.values`/`items` on the `rcParams` object.

```py
>>> from matplotlib import rcParams
>>> 
>>> isinstance(rcParams, dict)
True
>>> 
>>> print(*type(rcParams).__mro__, sep='\n')
<class 'matplotlib.RcParams'>
<class 'collections.abc.MutableMapping'>
<class 'collections.abc.Mapping'>
<class 'collections.abc.Collection'>
<class 'collections.abc.Sized'>
<class 'collections.abc.Iterable'>
<class 'collections.abc.Container'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'object'>
>>> "keys" in dir(rcParams)
True
>>> "values" in dir(rcParams)
True
>>> "items" in dir(rcParams)
True
```

See also:

- [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)